# Use result of one query as condition in another query using hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to use the information from one table as an input for another query.

query (required output):

```
SELECT * from maintable where year in ('2005','2006','2007','2008');
```

I have these years list in a separate table. Attached picture.
**This query is giving me errors:**

```
SELECT * from maintable where year in (SELECT * from picture_table) sub_data;
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of ways to implement this in Hive.

1. Using `IN` clause:
   If the picture table has *unique year*, then you need not use `DISTINCT` in the inner query.

`SELECT * FROM maintable a where a.year IN (SELECT year FROM picture_table);`

In case the `year` column is not unique in `picture_tale`, use `DISTINCT` keyword:

`SELECT * FROM maintable a where a.year IN (SELECT DISTINCT year FROM picture);`

2. Using `WHERE EXISTS` clause:

`SELECT * FROM maintable a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM picture_table b WHERE a.year = b.year);`

3. Using `JOIN`:

`SELECT a.* FROM maintable a INNER JOIN picture_table b ON (a.year = b.year) WHERE b.year IS NOT NULL;`

The advantage of using `IN` clause and `joins` is if any of the table is small enough to get cached in distributed cache, the query would be promoted as a `map join` (provided the property `hive.auto.convert.join=true`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I have 300 million records in maintable and around 5 records in picture_table. Which method would you suggest for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Kumar, in this case, both - Method 1 and 3 would be great!
Would request you to share the stats with us.
I would also like to point out that the `WHERE EXISTS` clause and `SEMI JOIN` where used in the past to perform intersection and minus operations during the time Hive wasn't evolved enough. These things are no more encouraged these days.
Cheers!

Comment: If my solutions solved your query, could you mark this as answer please?

Comment: I did it. Since am new contributor, it wouldn't show.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to specify alias for `maintable`:

```
 SELECT * from maintable a where a.year in (SELECT year from picture_table);
```